# Rails: "new or edit" path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, new-operator, edit, link-to

Is there a simple and straightforward way to provide a link in a view to either create a resource if it doesn't exist or edit the existing on if it does?

IE:

```
User has_one :profile
```

Currently I would be doing something like...

```
-if current_user.profile?
  = link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(current_user.profile)
-else
  = link_to 'Create Profile', new_profile_path
```

This is ok if it's the only way, but I've been trying to see if there's a "Rails Way" to do something like:

```
= link_to 'Manage Profile', new_or_edit_path(current_user.profile)
```

Is there any nice clean way to do something like that? Something like the view equivalent of `Model.find_or_create_by_attribute(....)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Write a helper to encapsulate the more complex part of the logic, then your views can be clean.

```
# profile_helper.rb
module ProfileHelper

  def new_or_edit_profile_path(profile)
    profile ? edit_profile_path(profile) : new_profile_path(profile)
  end

end
```

Now in your views:

```
link_to 'Manage Profile', new_or_edit_profile_path(current_user.profile)
```

Comment: That works. I suppose creating a helper yourself is kind of obvious... and would explain why there doesn't appear to be a similar built-in function. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I came across this same problem, but had a lot of models I wanted to do it for. It seemed tedious to have to write a new helper for each one so I came up with this:

```
def new_or_edit_path(model_type)
  if @parent.send(model_type)
    send("edit_#{model_type.to_s}_path", @parent.send(model_type))
  else
    send("new_#{model_type.to_s}_path", :parent_id => @parent.id)
  end
end
```

Then you can just call `new_or_edit_path :child` for any child of the parent model.

Comment: Where does @parent com from?

Answer (score 5):

Another way!

```
  <%=
     link_to_if(current_user.profile?, "Edit Profile",edit_profile_path(current_user.profile)) do
       link_to('Create Profile', new_profile_path)
     end
  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic way:

```
def new_or_edit_path(model)
  model.new_record? ? send("new_#{model.model_name.singular}_path", model) : send("edit_#{model.model_name.singular}_path", model)
end
```

Where `model` is your instance variable on your view. Example:

```
# new.html.erb from users
<%= link_to new_or_edit_path(@user) do %>Clear Form<% end %>
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
module ProfilesHelper

  def new_or_edit_profile_path(profile)
    profile ? edit_profile_path(profile) : new_profile_path(profile)
  end

end
```

and with your link like:

```
<%= link_to 'Manage Profile', new_or_edit_profile_path(@user.profile) %>
```